# Same attribute, different order id - possible?

Tags: magento

I have a big, big online store with **CE 1.9**, but I have a BIG problem...

I have a *several attributes* that have to be introduced in *several different product categories*, and since the `order id` of the attribute is shared across all categories, in some categories this attribute is displayed in the correct order, in other categories, not.

Is there any way (plugin or whatever) we can set different display orders for the same attribute?

**Example**:

`Attribute "X": Order id for Category "Y" is "1", for Category "A" is "3".`

Thank you for your help.